# Getting Timeout Request while using 3g

Tags: ios, afnetworking-2

I have encountered with time out request problem. I have developed an app using AFNetworking 2.0 network library, specifically, AFHTTPRequestOperationManager.

My app works cool over WIFI. However, when I switch to 3g, I am getting timeout request with _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey = 1 and error code = -1001!

Of course, it's not in every request but in 3 of 4 requests.

The question is: can i do something to less the errors?

Comment: increase the timeout value.

Comment: I increased my timeout value up to 120, the result is the same. Most importantly it works fine with VPN. I had to some tests and realised that with VPN I get all responses from server, 25 from 25 and, without VPN, the result is 4 from 25, the rest 21 is timeout error!

Comment: VPN through 3g? or Wifi? if you are having problems with 3g connections only, again increase the timeout value. 30000ms or 30sec may be a good value for 3g connections.